# Marketing Cloud SSJS Unsubscribe Returns Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Looking at using SSJS to unsubscribe from a Landing Page and from a Data Extension (via SSJS Activity). Of course there are AMP Script options, which we would like to avoid this due to SSJS flexibility, and Export/Import  which would like to avoid due to scrappines, but we would like to stick to SSJS where possible.

So here we go!

When trying

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("core","1");

  var MyList= List.Init("Newsletter - 991");
  var Subs = MyList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:"0123"});
  var Unsub = MyList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe({EmailAddress:"myemail@example.com", SubscriberKey:"0123"});
  var SubsStatus  = Stringify(Subs);
  var UnsubStatus  = Stringify(Unsub);
</script>

  <script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Write(SubsStatus);
    Write(UnsubStatus);
  </script>
```

SubsStatus returns all the Subscribers (I have this just for testing that MyList is all correct), but UnsubStatus returns "Error".

I based the Unsub on both the Help docs and https://gist.github.com/kylekeesling/2361012 which has an example.

Thoughts on what could be wrong and/or any way to get more error details?

Comment: Just tried using Function object with InvokeExecute and it comes back with the same error :/

Comment: Update 2: this code works in another org I have, and I managed to get the error details from the main org as

`[{"StatusCode":"Error","StatusMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","OrdinalID":0,"OrdinalIDSpecified":false,"Results":null,"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorCodeSpecified":false}]`

Any thoughts on potential settings which could be screwing this up?

Answer (score -2):

While initialization of LIST use the external key of that particular list, check for the subscriber key which you are retrieving and the same subscribers key and email address associated with that subscriber key should be used to unsubscribe.

Answer (score -2):

To unsubscribe only one subscriber you can try this.

```js
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("core","1");

  var subkey = "0123";
  var MyList= List.Init("Newsletter - 991");
  var Subs = MyList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:subkey});

   Write("RecordCount=" + Subs.length + "<br>"); // only for testing
   Write(Subs[0].EmailAddress + "<br>"); // only for testing

   if (Subs.length == 1) // because, one subscriber key would have one emailaddress
   {
     var Unsub = MyList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe({EmailAddress: Subs[0].EmailAddress, SubscriberKey: subkey});     
   }  

   Write(Stringify(Subs) + "<br>");  // only for testing
   Write(Stringify(Unsub) + "<br>"); // only for testing
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't vote down, but the likely reason this answer was so voted is that it contains only code, with no explanation. There's a *teach a man to fish* mentality around here, and handing out fish instead isn't particularly well regarded.